# Security considerations on EMV keys

Tags: security, key, payment-processing, emv

> Can someone help me understand how EMV Issuer Master Key rotation
> should be handled?

A first step would be to figure out if i have to talk about rotation or replacement.
I mean, as a best practice for key management i think that even these keys should be rotated periodically.
Obviously i would like to understand how to minimize the impact on the cards circulating knowing that the process would involve more parties (Issuer, card producer, scheme(?)).

> Is it possible in this process rotate keys? (generates a new version
> of a key with same key)